# What's a word that can be used when something, such as a document, is purposely bland?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word may also be used when referring to really dull signage for a government organization.

Comment: Are you looking for a word with a positive or negative connotation?

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps *prosaic* or *pedestrian* fits the bill.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go with *insipid*.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be *pabulum* (also spelled *pablum*):

> something (as writing or speech) that is insipid, simplistic, or bland

Comment: A good word, but the meaning would be unclear to many. I'm torn between promoting the word, or 'dumbing down' with a more commonly understood alternative.

Comment: Yep. Despite meaning simplistic, its "neoclassical" sound gives the impression of "simplistic… like the common plebeians."

Comment: Also reminds me of [baby food](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablum).

Answer (score 4):

There are already a few fine candidates on this page (I like *pedestrian* and *pablum*), but I am not sure if any of them actually have the connotation of *purposely*.

One word that does have that connotation, at least to me, would be *wishy-washy*. However, I'm not sure it could be applied to "really dull signage"; I would rather call that one *run-of-the-mill*.

Comment: Perhaps a nice alliterative phrasing would get the point across properly:  "The agency insists on spoonfeeding us this purposefully pedestrian pablum ..."

Answer (score 4):

**Anodyne**, which strictly speaking means *soothing*, is [often used](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/anodyne) to describe boring and/or non-commital official statements and publications.

For me at least, it carries overtones of wishing to avoid giving offense, with the (not always unintentional) side-effect of reducing both clarity and actual semantic content.

LATER - Several of the alternative proposed by others are words that *can* be used for OP's purpose, and to be honest OP's noun *signage* seems a bit too obscure to be worth looking for adjectives that *do* get used with that word.

But I'm still focussed on actual usage, and *anodyne statement* seems like a good enough variation to check. This [NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=anodyne%20statement&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10) confirms it's not only used, but gaining currency by the decade.

Answer (score 3):

It's called *boilerplate* and you usually find it in government and legal documents.

Comment: It's actually more refering to the dullness. It's like bland or boring.

Comment: Boilerplate *is* bland and boring. It's apparently designed to say as little as possible using as many words as possible. Originally it meant standardized pieces of text for use (and reuse) in official documents, but it has come to mean any dull, official prose.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's quite what they are after, boilerplate in the sense described, has a connection to any text that can be reused in new contexts without being changed much from the original. 

Where as the question is referring to 'dull signage' - a style as opposed to documentation.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters: the primary meaning of *boilerplate* is still "stock text" - reusable text that can be used without much thought or effort. The fact that such text is often dull and boring is merely a side effect.

Comment: Adding to Martha, calling a specific document "boilerplate" would be incorrect (and perhaps accusatory) if the document were in fact written for a specific occasion, regardless of dullness.

Answer (score 3):

my main suggestion:
**"monotonous"**  (which *can*, in fact, have a non-verbal meaning)

a few others:
**"lacking personality"**  (which is actually two words)
**"wordy"** (not a word I would use, but fits the requirements)
**"dull"**
**"needlessly redundant"** (again with two words)
**"emotionless"** (especially the government signage part)
**"professional"** (sadly...)

Comment: "Monotonous" was also my favourite. Normally it's used for speech but I even find it evocative when used of a document.

Answer (score 2):

[Milquetoast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspar_Milquetoast)! Such a colorful word for blandness.

Comment: Two problems with this: (1) In my mind, the primary attribute of a milquetoast is timidness, with a side order of ineffectiveness; any blandness is a side effect of such a person's unwillingness to be adventurous. (2) This adjective really only works for people, not for text.

Comment: (1) Yes, but blandness is the usual result of timidness. (2) I've often heard it applied to products in reviews. It would work for a story, but probably not for a government report. I think it would work for signage (street or indoor) which is supposed to be eye-catching.

Answer (score 1):

As you say "really dull signage", I presume that you're looking for a negative connotation.

Stodgy, vacuous; **turgid** would be my favourite.

Comment: Stodgy means conservative, which probably fits but refers to content, not style. Vacuous means meaningless or equivocal, so probably doesn't fit. Turgid means bombastic or grandiose, which is the opposite of what we want.

Comment: @potatos I was referring to the sense according to http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/turgid_1 : turgid adjective ( TOO SERIOUS )  /ˈtɜː.dʒɪd//ˈtɝː-/
formal (of speech, writing, style, etc.) too serious about its subject matter; boring.

Comment: @potatos and again according to Cambridge: vacuous adjective /ˈvæk.ju.əs/ formal
not expressing or showing intelligent thought or purpose. It could be  that we are differing according to American/British usage. Or some completely different culture, 'milquetoast' is unknown to Cambridge and dictionary.co.uk, I don't have my OED to hand.

Comment: I don't see how vacuous can work, even with that definition. Something may show a lot of intelligent thought and purpose, and still be written a very boring, dull and bland style.

Comment: @shreevatsar Perhaps you might like to make a better suggestion instead of picking holes in others'? 1. The OP is probably wise enough to make his own choice. 2. You're not adding any value to the thread.

Comment: Er, are you saying that there's something wrong with picking holes in others' submissions? I thought that's what comments are for (and also the downvote feature, which I like to use sparingly). I'm adding value to the thread by reducing the potential of one of the suggested options to mislead, and by adding more information about the implications of 'vacuous'. (It would be even more value if that particular suggestion were removed, but that's not in my hands. :p) We're all here to learn.

Comment: @shreevatsar It would appear that I haven't understood the objectives of english.so.com. I initially perceived it as a place where people could ask about the finer points of English and get answers from experienced speakers. Sadly, I have seen almost as much quibbling and hair-splitting as useful content, so I'll leave you to your squabbling and move back to SO, where the tone and attitude is more conducive to teaching and learning.

Comment: It is strange to see someone take so personally an observation about a word. :-) We *are* here to discuss language, too, after all… and was there anything wrong with the tone and attitude in pointing out that *vacuous* does not mean *bland*? I really meant to cause no offence; I thought I was just making an observation on the distinctness of the meanings.

Answer (score 1):

For the connotations of lack of style but still useful:

- utilitarian
- spartan

Comment: +1 I like *spartan* for that purpose. *Austere* is another that could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

**bureaucratese** is more for longer stretches of words than a sign, but captures the sense of boring, like turhid and stodgy mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Or use *bureaucratic*.

Comment: @Wayne: even though that literal change to an adjective fits the part of speech desired, the connotations of 'bureaucratic' don't seem to fit the requirements as well as 'bureaucratese'. You'd think they'd be the same but they don't feel that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Staid** just means “Serious, organized, and professional; sober”, according to Wiktionary. As it makes something of a virtue out of blandness, it makes it sound like it might be intentional. Other words along these lines include **sedate**, **temperate**, **moderate**, and **mild**. But I get the feeling there is a much better one that I’m missing.

Another tack is to try words that describe things used intentionally to put people to sleep: **lulling**, **soporific**, **anaesthetic**.

Answer (score 0):

I've also heard the word 'blasé' used to describe an object that was bland or boring and without any exciting or pleasurable qualities.

Comment: I've never come across that usage before. Are you sure you're not equating *uninterested* with *uninteresting*? One meaning of *blasé* is being *uninterested* in things because you've already had a surfeit of them. Another is *sophisticated*, which moves some way towards describing a person who might be considered interesting to others, even if they're not actually interested in much themselves.

Answer (score -1):

To make a precise and pointed reference to the fact that 'it had to be dull, so it is', we resort to 'Stupidized'. May not sound politically correct, but the term has been around in the technical field.